NextJS build error - no such file or directory for 500.html
I am migrating from Page Router to App router.
From
pages
  - 500.tsx


to
app
  - 500
     - page.tsx

However when I run yarn build/next build, below error shows
> Build error occurred
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/Users/CCC/Desktop/SourceTree/my-frontend/.next/export/500.html' -> '/Users/CCC/Desktop/SourceTree/my-frontend/.next/server/pages/500.html'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'rename',
  path: '/Users/CCC/Desktop/SourceTree/my-frontend/.next/export/500.html',
  dest: '/Users/CCC/Desktop/SourceTree/my-frontend/.next/server/pages/500.html'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.

I also checked next.config.js, but seems like nothing is related
const {
  PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER,
  PHASE_PRODUCTION_BUILD,
} = require("next/constants");

const withTM = require("next-transpile-modules")([
  // '@fullcalendar/common',
  // '@fullcalendar/react',
  // '@fullcalendar/daygrid',
  // '@fullcalendar/list',
  // '@fullcalendar/timegrid',
  // '@fullcalendar/timeline'
]);

module.exports = (phase, { defaultConfig }) => {
  const isDev = phase === PHASE_DEVELOPMENT_SERVER;
  const isProd =
    phase === PHASE_PRODUCTION_BUILD && process.env.STAGING !== "1";

  const env = {...};

  const config = {
    ...defaultConfig,
    env,
    swcMinify: true,
    reactStrictMode: false,
    webpack(config) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: ["@svgr/webpack"],
      });
      return config;
    },
   
  };

  return withTM(config);
};


I tried to remove .next folder and rebuild again, but it still doesn't work. What is happening?
Update
I tried to visit localhost:3000/500.
It shows the UI correctly, but in server it shows
GET /500 500

I checked the documentation and apparently it doesnt provide a way for us to customize the file, so it should be pages/500.(j|tsx) or nothing, but not sure because I didnt test this https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/custom-error

@artikandri But now I am using App router, so I removed the entire page folder

maybe rename to app/error.(j|tsx)? (disclaimer: i didnt test this) https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/error-handling

With app router it is no more possible to define custom 500 pages. What you can do is - Create a file : app/global-error.js.
This file will handle all errors in the App boundary which are not handled in the specific subtree.
From the docs:

global-error.js is the least granular error UI and can be considered
"catch-all" error handling for the whole application.

It can look like this (Copy pasting directly from the docs):
'use client'
 
export default function GlobalError({
  error,
  reset,
}: {
  error: Error & { digest?: string }
  reset: () => void
}) {
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>Something went wrong!</h2>
        <button onClick={() => reset()}>Try again</button>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

Note: global-error.js is only enabled in production. In development, our error overlay will show instead.
